# autocomplete light list shows only 20 items

Tags: django, django-autocomplete-light

I integrated autocomplete light with my django app.

In my registry i'm doing the following:

```
class HostAutocomplete( autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase ):
    search_fields = [ 'hostname' ]
    choices = Host.objects.all()
```

In my form i have:

```
hosts=autocomplete_light.MultipleChoiceField('HostAutocomplete')
```

Autoocomplete is working fine but the list which i'm getting contains only 20 items. Database has many more entries. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`limit_choices`](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#autocomplete_light.autocomplete.model.AutocompleteModel.limit_choices) property to your autocomplete class:

```
class HostAutocomplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    ...
    limit_choices = 50
```